# python exec of a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

With python (I am using 2.4 and 2.7) I'd need to "exec" a string statement like :
with these preexisting global strings say a, b

```
a="1"
b="2"
from the interactive shell :
    exec(if (a < b) :\n c=3)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this works with double quotes around the entire statement :
exec("if (a < b) :\n c=3")

since I need to call a python function from the C api to exec that statement which modifies global variables (which can't be done with eval if I understood correctly)
if I assign the statement to a string to be exec'd it works interactively :

```
>>> mystr="if (a < b) :\n c=3"
>>> exec(mystr)
```

if all global variables exists it works, calling from the C api the traceback gives error "expecting string or unicode object, found tuple" with, to the best of my understanding, all needed global variables existing

how should the string to be exec'd be written ?

if I try to nest 2 execs it seems instead to work both interactively and from C api with PyObject_CallFunction, PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs :

```
>>> mystr1="exec(if (a < b) :\n c=3), globals())"
>>> exec(mystr1)
```

to get the line interpreted back from python I use :

```
if ( PyErr_Occurred() ) 
                                {
                                    PyObject *ptype, *pvalue, *ptraceback;
                                    PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
                                    
                                    //Get error message
                                    char *pStrErrorMessage =NULL;
                                    if(pvalue)
                                    {
                                        PyObject *pstr=PyObject_Str(pvalue);
                                        pStrErrorMessage = PyString_AsString(pstr);
                                    }
```

Comment: Python 2.4 in 2021..?

Comment: You **have** to pass in a string to `exec`, but `exec` takes optional namespaces. Why not just use the C API to **directly** execute the Python source code, however?

Comment: Note that Python 2.7 is no longer supported. Python 2.4 is... ancient.

Comment: See the [`exec` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) on how to specify namespaces, which are just dictionaries.

Comment: Also, what is the `)` supposed to do in your Python string? It fails because it is *invalid Python code*. Use `mystr="if (a < b) :\n c=3"`, **without** the surplus closing `)` parenthesis.

Comment: The Python C-API equivalent are the [`PyRun_StringFlags()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_StringFlags) and [`PyRun_String()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_String) functions. Note that these *require* that you pass in the namespaces explicitly.

Comment: ignore the unneeded closing ) typo, my bad, the question is what could cause this error "expecting string or unicode object, found tuple" passing a string argument to a python function like : def ExecExpression(expression):
          exec(expression,globals())

Answer (score 2):

`exec` is expecting a string, not Python literals

```py
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> exec("if (a < b) :\n c=3")
>>> c
3
```

`eval` might also work with a different structure, but you may need to pass globals or locals to it for it to work in a function (which has different scoping to the shell)

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#eval

```py
>>> if eval("a + b", globals()) == 3:  # NOTE does not need globals in shell
...     c = 5
...
>>> c
5
```

Comment: hmm I don't mean to be silly, but stepping into python 2.7 interpreter, it seems to be something wrong in the colon : passed as string to PyRun_String(), it seems to enter an error clause in tok_get() of python ? should I escape the if clause termination colon or something ?

Comment: can you use a multiline-string `"""` or ternary `x = foo if bar else baz`?

Comment: multilined quotes """ work with interactive python 2.4, ternary doesn't seem to work >>> mystr="""c=5 if (a < b) else pass     """
>>> exec(mystr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "<string>", line 1
    c=5 if (a < b) else pass   I don't think I am having hallucinations because from C api, stepping the nested exec seems to have the \n removed ?my hunch is it interprets the first \ as continuation, and doesn't interpret \n can anyone with editing rights and sufficient knowledge of python clean this thread up because the typo makes it non reproducible

Comment: I THINK I found it : I need to pass a single newline character 10 decimal in the C string, and not 2 characters "\n", then you need at least 1 space of indentation in the 2nd line of the if clause

Comment: Maybe a raw (`r"\n"`) or escaped string (`"\\n"`) [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: it won't seem to accept raw r"\n", in my opinion "\\n" in C it would translate to backslash \ followed by n, anyway if anybody else has his nerves "rattled" from C api you can try binary single character LF 10 decimal it seems to accept it